# fminsearch with two variables

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

I am trying to minimize a 5 variable function with fminsearch. I only want to minimize the function for two variables. 
I have tried the following, without luck:

```
func = @(x,b) myfunction( x, y, z, a, b ); 
fminsearch(func,[x0,b0]);
```

**x** is a matrix of **N**x**M** dimensions, and **b** with **Y**x**Z** dimensions, so different dimensions. Same for the starting conditions **x0** and **b0**.

I have seen some similar questions asked, but still I cant solve this problem.

I get the following output when running the script:

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the function `fminsearch` only allows three inputs: the function handle, the initial values vector and the options for the optimization, something like: `fminsearch(@fun,x0,options)`

Fortunatelly, there's a small hack that can be done, you can put the extra parameters after the options, like this: `fminsearch(@fun,[x0 b0],options,z,a,b)`.

If you're not using any options, it should be like this: `fminsearch(@fun,[x0 b0],[],z,a,b)`.

Remember that inside the function you should *unpack* your variables `a` and `b`, something like:

```
function[obj]=func(x0,z,a,b)

x=x0(1)
y=x0(2)

%rest of the function

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I dit not quite get the last part of unpacking the variables.

Comment: I will. I tried your solution, with no luck. Since the matrices x and b are of different sizes, i stored them in a cell. Like this; c1{1}=x and c1{2}=b. Then i ran the following script; func = @(c1) myfunction( c1, y, z, a ); 
fminsearch(func,[c1{1} c1{2}]);. I still get the same error message like before.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, are you trying to minimize the objetive function by using two matrix as variable?

Comment: Yes I was. However, I figured it out.

Comment: Sure, I put together the matrixes to a single one, and attached it to a single variable. This solved my problem.